# How can I get MetaMask to use the corresponding token to display balances?

Tags: ethereum, metamask

[image: MetaMask ScreenCap]

I've noticed that anytime I want to test some token, I have to go into MetaMask and a load in the custom address off of etherscan, rather than using the provided tokens found within MetaMask. The picture above shows Dai (with the two Dai labels: the one provided by MetaMask and the one coming from the custom Dai address) within Rinkeby. However, this has been an issue for me whether it was dealing with other ERC20 tokens such as LINK or other networks (e.g. Ropsten and Kovan).

Could I be doing something incorrect when sending tokens? Are the provided token labels just for Mainnet?

Comment: Are you trying to add a custom token? MetaMask has an interrnal data and  whitelist for well-known mainnet tokens if you are asking that. Tokens are identified by their smart contract address.

Comment: I guess another way of putting this is if I were to use an Ethereum faucet, regardless of the network, once I am send ETH, MetaMask will automatically update the wallet (e.g. above with 18.5888 eth). However, if I were to use a Dai faucet (or any other ERC20 based token), I have to load in the token contract address manually (the .532 Dai), instead of MetaMask automatically recognizing the tokens I have (the default with 0 Dai).

Comment: Unfortunately, currently there is no way for MetaMask to auto recognize testnet tokens I am afraid.

Comment: Yea, I saw this [post](https://github.com/MetaMask/faq/blob/master/USERS.md#managing-tokens) on the FAQ and I think you're right. 
But then the question is why even have the token there in the first place?